# I am running this code through Xcode and i am getting build failed with the error

Tags: c++, xcode

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "standardDeviation(double*)", referenced from:       _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double standardDeviation(double []);

int main(){
    double array[] =  {2, 11, 4, 5, 9, 5, 4, 12, 7, 8, 9, 3, 7, 4, 12, 10,9, 6, 9, 4};
    standardDeviation(array);
    return 0;
}

double standardDeviation(double arrary){
    cout << arrary;
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: your prototype is `[]`, your implementation is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of standardDeviation is looking for a double which you are calling array. You are trying to pass in a array of doubles. The way c++ handles a array is it saves a location pointer to the variable name and when you give it a input (ex array[2]) it moves the space of that many doubles over in memory.

So what the compiler is complaining about is that you told it a double was coming and it got a pointer to a double.

Here's some info on [pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm) and [arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) which should help flesh out what I stated above.

To fix this you should change your prototype to `double standardDeviation(double array[]);` and then copy that down to your function definition. (As noted by KevinDTrimm above)

Comment: No, the linker is complaining that no method matches his call.  It's not a pointer problem at all (besides the fact that pointers and scalars are not equal in method definitions)

Comment: @KevinDTimm The problem is that your prototype and function definition do not match (the prototype specifies array and the definition says it is a double). I expanded my answer explaining how to fix this.